# Prove inequality on expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value, jensen-inequality

How do I prove that $(E[X_1])^q \leq E([\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j])^q \leq E\bigg[X_1\bigg(\frac{X_1+(n-1)\mu}{n}\bigg)^{q-1}\bigg]$ using Jensen's inequality? I tried using $\phi(x) = x^q$ and $x^q = xx^{q-1}$ but I don't know how to use Jensen's Inequality for conditional expectations. Also, $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are independent random variables with $X_1 > 0, E[X_1]=\mu$ and $E[X_1^q]< \infty, 1<q\leq 2$

Comment: You notation is confusing. By, $E[X_1]^q$, do you mean $E[X_1^q]$ or $(E[X_1])^q$ ?

Comment: @dohmatob it is $(E[X_1])^q$, I will edit if it is better. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Welcome to SE! If you say $E[X_1]^q$ means $(E[X_1])^q$ (which I doubt), then when do you mean by the condition "$E[X_1]^q < \infty$" ? Isn't it sufficient to ask for $E[X_1] := \mu < \infty$ ? Maybe you mean the moment condition "$E[X_1^q] < \infty$" (which is stronger than $E[X_1] < \infty$). I advice, you take some time to read you question and be sure that everything makes sense. People won't pay much attention to your question if it has many notation errors / inconsistencies.

Comment: @dohmatob now everything is correct. This is an exercise I really need help.

Comment: Just to confirm that in the last term of the inequality there isn't a missing $n^{2-q}$ factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that there is a $n^{q-2}$ factor missing in your statement.

Here is what I got:

Jensen's inequality implies that

$$(E[X_1])^q=\left(E\Big[\tfrac{X_1+\ldots+ X_n}{n}\big]\right)^q\leq E\Big(\tfrac{X_1+\ldots+ X_n}{n}\Big)^q$$

As $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ ia an i.i.d. family
$$
\begin{align}
E\left[\Big(\tfrac{X_1+\ldots+ X_n}{n}\Big)\Big(\tfrac{X_1+\ldots+ X_n}{n}\Big)^{q-1}\right]&=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{j=1}E\left[X_j\Big(\tfrac{X_1+\ldots+ X_n}{n}\Big)^{q-1}\right]\\
&= E\left[X_1\Big(\tfrac{X_1+\ldots+ X_n}{n}\Big)^{q-1}\right]\\
&=E\left[X_1 E \left[\Big(\tfrac{X_1+\ldots+ X_n}{n}\Big)^{q-1}|X_1\right]\right]
\end{align}
$$

Since $0<q-1\leq 1$,

$$
\Big(\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n}\Big)^{q-1}\leq\frac{X^{q-1}}{n^{q-1}}+\ldots +\frac{X^{q-1}_n}{n^{q-1}}
$$

Integrating with respect the conditional probability given $X_1$ leads to

$$
\begin{align}
E\left[\Big(\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n}\Big)^{q-1}|X_1\right]&\leq \frac{X^{q-1}_1}{n^{q-1}}+\frac{E[X^{q-1}_2]}{n^{q-1}}+\ldots + \frac{E[X^{q-1}_n]}
{n^{q-1}}\\
&\leq \frac{X^{q-1}_1}{n^{q-1}}+\frac{(E[X_2])^{q-1}}{n^{q-1}}+\ldots + \frac{(E[X_n])^{q-1}}{n^{q-1}}\\
&= 
n\frac{X^{q-1}+(n-1)\mu^{q-1}}{nn^{q-1}}\leq n\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big(\frac{X_1}{n}+\frac{\mu}{n}+\ldots+\frac{\mu}{n}\Big)\Big)^{q-1}\\
&=n^{2-q}\Big(\frac{X_1+(n-1)\mu}{n}\Big)^{q-1}
\end{align}
$$

Here we have twice used Jensen's inequality for the concave function $x\mapsto x^{q-1}$. Putting things together

$$\mu^q=(E[X_1])^p\leq n^{q-2}E\left[X_1\Big(\frac{X_1+(n-1)\mu}{n}\Big)^{q-1}\right]
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Pretty clear now!

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{split}
(E[X_1])^q &\overset{(a)}{=} \left(E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right]\right)^q \overset{(b)}{\le} E\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^q\right]\\
& \overset{(c)}{=} E\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^{q-1}\right]\\
&\overset{(d)}{=}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}E\left[X_j\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^{q-1}\right],
\end{split}
$$
where

- *(a)* is because the $X_i$'s are iid and so $E[X_i] = E[X_1]$ for all $i$.
- *(b)* is Jensen's inequality for the convex function $x \mapsto x^q$.
- *(c)* Just expanding things out.

Try to continue from here...

Comment: Ok, perfect. Will try to solve it now. Thanks a lot!